# Django: Unable to pass keyword arguments to class-based form

Tags: python, django

I have a list consisting of a model `products` and each `products` instance has their own `variants`. Without using the admin, I want to go and see my products at `products/<pk>/` and than add variants for each product instance by going to `products/<pk>/add-variant/`using class-based forms. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the product instance's id to the `CreateVariant` form, as I keep getting the error:

> Reverse for 'variant-create' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vendor/products/(?P\d+)/add-variant/$']

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_location)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Variant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    variant_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_location, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kargs={'pk': self.product_id})
```

views.py:

```
#...

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Product
        template_name = 'gravel/product_detail.html'

class VariantCreate(CreateView):
            model = Variant
            template_name = 'gravel/add_variant.html'
            fields = ['name', 'description', 'variant_image', 'price', 'available']

class VariantUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Variant
    template_name = 'gravel/update_variant.html'
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'variant_image', 'price', 'available']

class VariantDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Variant
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_detail_view')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(), name="product-list" ),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="product-detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/add-variant/$', VariantCreate.as_view(), name="variant-create"),
#... ]
```

Of course, there are a few similar questions like this already here on Stack, however none of them have been able to help me. I can't figure out any ways to pass the `id` of the given `products` instance so that when I go to, for example, `products/1/add-variant`, it adds that variant for product.id = 1. But as you can see from the error above, I'm not able to get any variables passed.

Comment: Override post method in `VariantCreate` view class and get the id through `kwargs['pk']`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj So you mean to use `get_context_data` on the view class? I'm not sure that would help since the instance is the Variant not the Product